# Get item of list in dataframe column using loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe `df` like this :

```
    date        item
    2019-03-29  [book,pencil]
    ...
```

I want to get every item  in list using loop. this is what I've tried:

```
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for x in df['attributeName'][i]:
            print(x)
```

But i got every single character. The desired output is:

```
    book
    pencil
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: try `df.iterrows()`

Comment: @YashKumarAtri No, don't try `df.iterrows()`. There's bad advice flying from every direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df2['item'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

A better alternative.. [A Common Pitfall: Exploding Columns of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

```
pd.DataFrame(df2['item'].tolist()).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
0      book
1    pencil
dtype: object
```

Comment: [Don't use `apply(pd.Series)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) (you'll need to scroll to find it). `pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist())` is always better.